# Firestore Compound Interval Date Query

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all documents that have a date field for the current date, e.g., 2020-10-02. To do so, I implemented the following:

```
const todayStart = new Date();
todayStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // 2020-10-02T00:00:00.000Z
const todayEnd = new Date();
todayEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 0); // 2020-10-02T23:59:59.000Z 
console.log(todayStart)
console.log(todayEnd)
const querySnapshot = await firestore
      .collection("CourseEvents")
      .where("date", ">=", todayStart)
      .where("date", "<=", todayEnd)
      .get();
```

This is semi-working. I have a document with the following Timestamp: *October 2, 2020 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+2*

For some reason, I can not get this document.

Any tipps for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All timestamps are internally represented in UTC (that's the Z at the end of the string representation of the Date object you built).  However, timestamps are rendered in the Firebase console using the timezone of your local machine (that's UTC+2 in your case).  So, the timestamp in the document that you see in the console is actually two hours ahead of UTC, which is out of the range of your query.

You will either have to adjust your query, or adjust the timestamp in the document so that the range overlaps what's in the document.

Comment: Maybe I do not get it but does this mean that the date within the document is October 2, 2020 at **10:00:00 AM**? If so, then it should be within the range since 00:00 <= 10:00 <=23:59

Comment: No, the date in the document is Oct 2, 2AM UTC.  +2 hour offset.

Comment: Do you mean then Oct **3**, 2AM? 02:00 is also between 00:00 and 23:59 of the Oct 2nd

Comment: Sorry, went two hours the wrong direction. 10PM Oct 1.